# Supporting optional parameter value in Swift property wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, wrapper, option-type, nullable

I have below property wrapper for user defaults,

```
@propertyWrapper
class MyUserDefaultWrapper<T> {
    let key: String
    let defaultValue: T

    init(_ key: String, defaultValue: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.defaultValue = defaultValue
    }

    var wrappedValue: T {
        get {
            let suit = UserDefaults.standard
            return suit?.object(forKey: key) as? T ?? defaultValue
        }
        set {
            let suit = UserDefaults.standard
            suit?.set(newValue, forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

I am defining it like,

```
struct MyUserDefaultsCommon{
    @MyUserDefaultWrapper("yearOfBirth", defaultValue: 1980)
    static var yearOfBirth: Int
}
```

And calling it like,

```
MyUserDefaultsCommon.yearOfBirth = 2010
```

When I set default value to `nil` build is failed with a sig abrt.

How can I restrict passing optional default value from property wrapper class? Or is there any other way around?

Comment: When you set `defaultValue` to `nil` do you change property type to `Optional` too? Like, in your example it should be ```static var yearOfBirth: Int?``` instead of `Int`

Comment: If it's nil, you'll want to remove the object for the key, not set it to nil.

Comment: @user28434 if its Int? instead of Int. it gets runtimes error when i set a nil value.

Comment: I haven't run your code, but as a rule, you remove UserDefaults, not set them to nil. It would be far simpler to check if the value and if it's nil, remove the key from user defaults or if it's not nil, update the value.

Comment: @Adrian i want to restrict with build error if anyone of my team try to use nil as default value. Because of a big team its not sufficient to make a rule. I cannot be assuming that everyone follow my rule.

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan inside this, `set { // blah blah}`, just check for nil. If `newValue` is nil, then remove the key in `UserDefaults`, otherwise set it.

Comment: Does the code even compile? As `UserDefaults.standard` is non-optional `suit?` should throw an error.

Comment: @vadian it does work fine cz I am using `suit?.set`. But when I set default value to `nil` build fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I restrict passing optional default value from property wrapper class?

[This is (was) a bug in Swift.](https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-11722) It's been fixed, and [should be in the next release of 5.1](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/27226). You should not be able to pass `nil` here.